# Выделение памяти в Си

Tags: c, указатели

Я рассматриваю довольно не простой случай

```
char *(*array[10])[10];
```

Трактуется, по всей видимости, это так
*array - десятиэлементный массив указателей на десятиэлементый массив указателей*. Интуитивно ощущается, что это трехмерный массив. При этом сам массив массивов, состоящих из массивов :) инициализирован. Массивы, которые должны содержать массивы - тоже инициализирован. Но массивы как элементы массива не инициализированы. Проще говоря:

```
array[0][0]
```

Не содержит ошибки в обращении, в то время как

```
array[0][0][0]
```

Содержит ошибку, потому что надо выделить память под это. 
Как это сделать?

```
*(array[0])[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
```

Выдает ошибку. Спасибо заранее за ответ и комментарии!

Comment: Тут приоритет * и [] - спорный момент - нужно читать приоритеты или добавить скобки.

Comment: У меня не выдаёт ошибку (ВС5)

Comment: Но вначале нужно выделить память под array[0]. Ведь это ссылка. хотя бы так `(void*)array[0] = malloc( 4)` если лень узнавать тип.

Comment: Зачем? Он и так выделяет десятиэлементный массив указателей

Comment: @nick_n_a Вы бы поставили компилятор посовременнее, а то BC5 уже за 20 лет перевалило... `(void*)array[0] = malloc(4)` не должно компилироваться (`(void*)array[0]` - это rvalue), но можно просто сделать `array[0] = malloc(4)`.

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен. Такая структура допускает множество разных независимых интерпретаций. Среди них нет единственно "правильной".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> десятиэлементный массив указателей на десятиэлементый массив указателей

Совершенно верно.

> Интуитивно ощущается, что это трехмерный массив.

Не существует никакой однозначной интерпретации, не существует однозначного ответа и не существует единственно правильного способа выделения памяти. Интерпретаций можно придумать много разных.

Если доступаться к такой структуре как `array[i][j][k]`, то мы полагаем, что `array[i]` - это указатель на массив, состоящий из массивов `char *[10]`. Тогда `array[i][j]` - это конкретный массив `char *[10]`. Тогда `array[i][j][k]` - это конкретный `char *`. Тогда `array` - это трехмерный массив из элементов типа `char *`, получаемых как `array[i][j][k]`. (А если каждый `char *` считать указателем на свой подмассив, то тогда мы получаем уже *четырехмерный* массив из `char`).

```
char *(*array[10])[10];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  array[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof *array[i]);

// Получили массив array[10][20][10]

char hw[] = "Hello World!";
array[5][14][8] = hw;
// Трехмерный?

assert(array[5][14][8][1] == 'e');
// А может все таки четырехмерный?
```

Если доступаться к такой структуре как `(*array[i])[j][k]`, то мы полагаем, что `array[i]` - это указатель на единственный массив `char *[10]`, который содержит указатели на некие символьные подмассивы. Тогда `array` - это трехмерный массив из элементов типа `char`, получаемых как `(*array[i])[j][k]`.

```
char *(*array[10])[10];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  array[i] = malloc(sizeof *array[i]);

  for (unsigned j = 0; j < 10; ++i)
    (*array[i])[j] = malloc(123 * sizeof *(*array[i])[j]);
}

(*array[5])[5][8] = 'h';
(*array[3])[4][1] = 'w';
```

То есть ваш вопрос по пусть эквивалентен вопросу про `int *p` - это указатель на массив или указатель на единичный `int`? Никакого однозначного ответа на такой вопрос нет и быть не может. Как сделаете, так и будет.

Comment: По сути, второй вариант - это частный случай первого, только размер подмассивов равен 1.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Совершенно верно. Опять же: это вопрос из разряда `int i = 45; int *p = &i;` - является ли `p` указателем на массив или нет? Кто-то скажет "нет", а кто то скажет, что "да, это именно массив", именно частный случай: массив размера 1. Можно спокойно делать `p[0] = 123;`. В вопросах адресной арифметики, что является "массивом", а что не является - это вопрос произвольного выбора терминологии/интерпретации.

Answer (score 1):

Это делается вот так:

```
const int a = 5, b = 6;

char *(*array[10])[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*[10]) * a);
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        array[i][j][k] = malloc(b);
}
```

Нет необходимости явно приводить указатели, которые возвращает `malloc`, к нужному типу. По стандарту компилятор должен делать это сам.

Если компилятор почему-то этого не делает, то так:

```
const int a = 5, b = 6;

char *(*array[10])[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array[i] = (char*(*)[10])malloc(sizeof(char*[10]) * a);
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        array[i][j][k] = (char*)malloc(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень сильно заморочился по этому поводу, спасибо за ответы, которые здесь оставили другие уважаемые пользователи. Действительно HolyBlackCat был прав, что это скорее четырех элементный массив и сейчас объясню, почему я сделал ошибку в рассуждении. Как было сказано: это *десятиэлементный массив указателей на десятиэлементный массив указателей*. Все вёрно, но ошибка в моих рассуждениях заключалась в том, что для меня первая часть предложения *десятиэлементный массив* в каждом своем элементе уже содержит ссылку на начало десятиэлементного массива. Проще говоря, вспомните, как бы вы динамически создавали трехмерный массив. *В чем ошибка?* Правильно интерпретировать так: десятиэлементый массив содержит указатели, по которым могут создаваться массивы размером от одного до n. Каждый элемент новосозданного массива содержит указатель на массив указателей (двумерный массив). Массив указателей фиксирован - его размер десять. Теперь для каждого элемента массива по указателю нужно создать новый массив.
Графически это выглядело бы так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так как я уже сталкавался с template, предлагаю воспользоваться именно ним. template- позволяет подставить тип, и упрощает задачу "определения размера переменной".

```
char *(*array[10])[10]; // Массив уже содержит 10 елементов
```

Массив двухмерный, где одно из измерений - ссылка на тип размером в 10 ссылок, а второе измерение - массив из 10 первых, находящийся в памяти стека или глобальных переменных. Т.е. одно из измерений нужно инициализировать.
`char *` - можно условно назвать третьим измерением, но тогда "неопределенного размера".

```
template <typename T> void malloc_ref(T& data) {
    (void*)&data = malloc(sizeof(*data)); 
    }

// тогда задача упрощается
//Тогда нужно обойти массив
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);i++) {
  malloc_ref(array[i]);
  // или так (void*)array[i] = malloc(sizeof(*array[0]));
  }
// array - содержит двухмерный массив, одно измерение в памяти стека 
// или глобальных переменных, второе из malloc
// А уже теперь можно делать так
char hw[] = "Hello World!";
(*array[5])[1]= hw;
// или так
(*array[5])[1]= (char*)malloc(4); // Зарезервировать память на 3-е измерение
(*array[5])[1][0]= 'h';
(*array[5])[1][1]= 'w';
(*array[5])[1][2]= 0;
(*array[5])[1][3]= 0;
```